How to give a 3d shadow effect to a layout
I want to replicate this type of shadow in my layout
Image
currently im making this images and using it in my app i have approx 50+ images like this , but i dont think so this is a good approach, instead i wnat to replacate it with a single layout, i can make the rest of the part includes the border the background and the textview, but don't know about the shadow
This is how it looks in app
image
could anyone provide a solution ?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
